# Fixed form not working for GNU Fortran compiler

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am using the latest version of MinGW to compile a reduced part of a module I am working on. The module this is extracted from is not my own making so I need to adapt it. It is a .FOR file so I am assuming it is under fixed format.

The source code is shown below:

```
      module ModGlobalConstants

      implicit none

        ! General constants
        integer, parameter :: MAX_EXTENSION_LENGTH = 20
        integer, parameter :: MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 1000
        integer, parameter :: INITIAL_STEP = 1
        integer, parameter :: MAXIMUM_STEP = 100000
        integer, parameter :: STRESS_VECTOR_SIZE = 6
        integer, parameter :: DOF_VECTOR_SIZE = 3
        integer, parameter :: N_DIM = 3
        integer, parameter :: N_ELEMENT_NODES = 4
        integer, parameter :: ID_UNDEFINED = -1
        integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
        real(dp), parameter :: ZERO = 0.0

        double precision, dimension(3), parameter :: 
     + DEFAULT_GRAVITY_DIRECTION = (/ 0.0, -1.0, 0.0 /)
        double precision, parameter :: DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION = 9.81


      contains 
         subroutine TrySomeVariables
                print *, MAX_EXTENSION_LENGTH
                print *, DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION
            end subroutine TrySomeVariables


      end module ModGlobalConstants
```

When I compile this on the MinGW cmd prompt this is what I get:

```
D:\TEMP\TRUNK-MINGW\ALL>gfortran TEMP.FOR
TEMP.FOR:18:72:

         double precision, dimension(3), parameter ::
                                                                        1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
TEMP.FOR:19:7:

   + DEFAULT_GRAVITY_DIRECTION = (/ 0.0, -1.0, 0.0 /)
       1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

According to [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/03_basics.html) link line continuation in fixed form format is done by including a generic symbol (`+` in the above code sample) on column 6 of the code. I believe this is exactly what I have done. Why does the compiler throw an error on the definition line for `DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION`?

**EDIT**

Following the answer from @VladimirF I removed all the tabs. However I do not agree that the `+` should be in column 5 but rather column 6 (see link above).

I also shortened the code to better identify the source of error:

```
      module ModGlobalConstants

      implicit none

! General constants


      double precision, dimension(3), parameter :: 
     +DEFAULT_GRAVITY_DIRECTION = (/ 0.0, -1.0, 0.0 /)
      double precision, parameter :: 
     +DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION = 9.81

      contains 
      subroutine TrySomeVariables
            print *, MAX_EXTENSION_LENGTH
            print *, DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION
      end subroutine TrySomeVariables
      end module ModGlobalConstants
```

However when I try to generate the object file I get similar problems:

```
D:\TEMP\TRUNK-MINGW\temp>gfortran -c TEMP.FOR -o TEMP.o
TEMP.FOR:8:72:

       double precision, dimension(3), parameter ::
                                                                        1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
TEMP.FOR:9:7:

   +DEFAULT_GRAVITY_DIRECTION = (/ 0.0, -1.0, 0.0 /)
       1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
TEMP.FOR:10:72:

       double precision, parameter ::
                                                                        1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
TEMP.FOR:11:7:

   +DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION = 9.81
       1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
TEMP.FOR:16:49:

             print *, DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION
                                                 1
Error: Symbol 'default_gravity_acceleration' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
TEMP.FOR:15:41:

             print *, MAX_EXTENSION_LENGTH
                                         1
Error: Symbol 'max_extension_length' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Comment: Yes, it is. The pasted code starts at the 4th column

Comment: You say your gravity points in the y direction? That's blasphemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some TAB characters in your file. They are not allowed by standard Fortran and are *very* confusing in fixed form. Delete them. Use `-Wall` to find them.

Also your line `DEFAULT_GRAVITY_ACCELERATION = 9.81` is too long.

Check that the + is exactly in column 6 and the characters before are only spaces, no TABs. Delete all other TABs too.

Comment: How to use `-Wall`? could you please provide a sample command?

Comment: `gfortran -Wall yourfile.for` Read the manual for many more useful flags to help you find bugs, make it run faster and much more.

Comment: I fixed the tab problem. Please note the + needs to be in column 6.  I'm still getting problems though. Please check out the edit to the original question.

Comment: Nevermind yes I got it. Removing the tabs solved the problem... Notepad++ has an option which disables automatic addition of tabs